# The restaurant scene in Au Revoir Les Enfants -- what did the director intend?

Tags: au-revoir-les-enfants

The scene is a fancy place where the mother of one of the main characters (I am not sure of details, I only saw this clip after reading about it) and maybe his school friend are eating when the French Milice ask to see one old man's papers and upon discovering he is Jewish, tell him very nastily that he should know not to be eating there.

Few in the place seem sympathetic to the Milice (except one woman says, They are right, send him to Moscow! at which the old man just smiles bitterly -- this is the Jew-communist thing fascists like to assert) and one of the kids calls them collaborators which angers the Milice men very much.

Soon a nazi officer, also eating there, stands up and says, Go away, we don't want you here.

At this moment I was sure the nazi was addressing the old Jewish guy, but it is the Milice who slink out.

My question is, did the writer/director intend the viewer to be confused about this, eventually surprising the viewer by the nazi behaving in an apparently decent way? (In fact, the nazi was just showing off for the attractive woman with the boys, at least that is what one of the boys says.)

That really is my entire question, what the director's intent was. I do not know the details of the nazi occupation: I do know that the French enforced nazi rules very seriously, sometimes treating Jews worse than the nazis asked. I do not know how realistic the scene was -- whether a Jew could be moving about freely or not and whether a nazi officer would take the side of a Jew, even to impress a woman. The nazi's stance could simply have been, Why are these oafs ruining lunch for everyone in this very nice place. (As nice as it looked, due to war shortages all they served to every diner was rabbit -- I have read about specifically rabbit being what many ate, I think Sartre mentions this -- the restaurant was all about appearances, not substance and war sucks.)

Comment: Would you be horrified if I edited your question to remove what I think is not relevant and make it clearer (to me) what you are asking?  You can always revert my edit if you don't like it - but I'd like to try to tighten-up what is a perfectly good question.

Comment: @iandotkelly: Someone probably needs to have watched the movie or knows the analysis of the scene to answer the question which is about Malle's intent -- this is a question about film making techniques which I think is unusual for here. I described what occurs in the scene and I am happy with the question as is. I also disagree about the tag policy which I explained carefully in Meta but if that's the rule/custom of this stackexchange, I will accept it However, I think it would be productively changed.